# How to merge row data where value exists in column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

after many years, this is my first question to StackOverflow and I'm at a loss.

I'm a magento user, and when you export product data from magento, it will export the data at a global level, plus any data that has been maintained at a store level as a seperate row

Here's an example for a couple of products

| sku | store_view_code | product_online | visibility | url | is_in-stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 |  | 1 | Not Visible | /this-product | 1 |
| ABC1 | default | 2 | Catalog |  |  |
| ABC2 |  | 1 | Not Visible | /that-product | 1 |
| ABC2 | default |  |  | /diff-product |  |

In Magento, the default store settings override the global settings, so I need to merge both these rows into 1, where the default value supercedes the global (blank) value, i.e

| sku | store_view_code | product_online | visibility | url | is_in-stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | default | 2 | Catalog | /this-product | 1 |
| ABC2 | default | 1 | Not Visible | /diff-product | 1 |

So, I've imported the CSV data into Google Sheets, but I cannot figure out how to do this, I've tried various QUERY functions, ARRAYFORMULA, I think it could be answered by NOT EXISTS but Google Sheets can't do that.

Now it won't be me running this process, so I'd like for it to work this out without having to tell the user to drag down formulas or anything like that

I've tried creating multiple sheets, each for a column in the table, so it returns just those rows where a value has been maintained for the store_view_code for that column, then I was thinking I could use something like NOT EXISTS to check if there's an entry for that sku, and if so, use that, but then hit a dead end. I can't even see how you can use subqueries.

EDIT: I've tried importing the data into BigQuery as well, but Magento's product data contains nested extended attributes (essentially columns within a column), and you can't import CSV's with nested data. I would just delete that column but it contains data I need. I've also tried exporting this data as JSON then importing that into BigQuery, but every publicly available JSON exporter function doesn't seem to work any more.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what is the "hierarchy" when a sku has more than one value for a given field?

Comment: @MattKing the value in the "store_view_code = default" line supercedes whatevers in the "store_view_code = blank" line except for when the "store_view_code = default" value is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(sku_,A2:A, svc_,B2:B, cat_,B2:F,
     map(unique(tocol(sku_,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,bycol(sort(cat_,1,1),lambda(Λ,iferror(+tocol(filter(Λ,sort(sku_,svc_,1)=Σ),1))))})))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this! My spreadsheet has aroudn 50,000 rows, so it's taking a long time to run, but am chunking into sections of 500 rows and it seems to be working